# Convergence of $\sum \frac {\log n} {(n+1)^{1/n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Convergence of $\sum \frac {\log n} {(n+1)^{1/n}}$

**Attempt:** $f(n) = \frac {\log n} {(n+1)^{1/n}} $~ $\frac {\log n}{n^{1/n}}$

I don't seem to have a clue how to proceed ahead from here. Could somebody please guide me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac12 \le \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^{1/n}} \le 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a_n=\frac{\log{n}}{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}} \to +\infty$$

So the series cannot converge.

A necessary condition for a series $\sum_na_n$ to converge is that $a_n \to 0$

Comment: (+1), but $(n+1)^{1/n}\to 1$ is probably a fact that the OP does not know, or has not thought to use...

Answer (score 1):

Recall that

$$(n+1)^{1/n}=e^{\frac{\log(1+n)}{n}}\to 1$$

and then

$$ \frac {\log n} {(n+1)^{1/n}}\to \infty$$